# Android GoogleMap a square appears rectangle

Tags: java, android

I've created a `GoogleMap` object and drawn a polygon with a square vertex as shown in the figure, but the square appears an oblong. What am I doing wrong?

This is a fragment of the code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;


    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng enidh = new LatLng(38.6925785, -9.2955145);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(enidh).title("Marker in ENIDH"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(enidh, 10.0f));


    mBoats[0] = mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(38.680026, -9.2846651),
                    new LatLng(38.690026, -9.2846651),
                    new LatLng(38.690026, -9.2946651),
                    new LatLng(38.680026, -9.2946651),
                    new LatLng(38.680026, -9.2846651))
            .fillColor(Color.CYAN)
            .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
            .strokeWidth(5));
```

[This is the square (rectangle) appearance in android app emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3n4Sx.jpg)

Comment: Square is a rectangle :)

Comment: @miensol He means that the square appears as an oblong. I've edited the question.

Comment: Thanks Robert, it is a my poor English.

Comment: Wait until you zoom out and the sides appear round ;) If you really need a square add a marker.

Comment: @Msimao don't worry, very few native English speakers know the difference between a rectangle and an oblong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've specified coordinates of the `Polygon` using `LatLng`. However the distances (i.e. in km) represented by 1 longitude and 1 latitude are [not the same](http://geography.about.com/library/faq/blqzdistancedegree.htm):

> Each degree of latitude is approximately 69 miles (111 kilometers)
>   apart. The range varies (due to the earth's slightly ellipsoid shape)
>   from 68.703 miles (110.567 km) at the equator to 69.407 (111.699 km)
>   at the poles. This is convenient because each minute (1/60th of a
>   degree) is approximately one mile.
>
> A degree of longitude is widest at the equator at 69.172 miles
>   (111.321) and gradually shrinks to zero at the poles. At 40° north or
>   south the distance between a degree of longitude is 53 miles (85 km).

Thus even though the edges lengths of polygon you've created have the same *unit-less* value you get a rectangle that is not a square.

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding polygon properly. You have to use 4 different coordinates as corners of rectangle like this.

```
// Instantiates a new Polyline object and adds points to define a rectangle
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0))
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0))  // North of the previous point, but at the same longitude
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2))  // Same latitude, and 30km to the west
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2))  // Same longitude, and 16km to the south
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)); // Closes the polyline.

// Get back the mutable Polyline
Polyline polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

Source : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes

Comment: I think that example from developers.google it is quite the same that I use. I made with the second decimal number increments (smaller square).

Comment: Your all points are same. Use 4 different points as corner coordinates to make square.